# Error with prettier in ReactJS app: Expected atom at position 0

Tags: reactjs, babeljs, netlify, prettier

I am trying to deploy my ReactJS [app](https://github.com/appukuttan-shailesh/ebrains-live-papers/tree/custom_section_formatter) (note: branch is `custom_section_formatter`) on Netlify. Previously everything worked fine, but today after making some changes I keep getting this error:

> 4:54:51 PM: ./node_modules/prettier/standalone.js

> 4:54:51 PM: SyntaxError: /opt/build/repo/apps/live-paper-builder/node_modules/prettier/standalone.js: Expected atom at position 0

> 4:54:51 PM:     {{(.+?)}}

> 4:54:51 PM:     ^

> 4:54:51 PM: error Command failed with exit code 1.

From everything I have searched on the web, it seems to be related to a [BabelJS issue](https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/8951), but that apparently has been resolved. So not sure why I still get this error.
My build logs are [here](https://app.netlify.com/sites/live-paper-builder/deploys/61def7fc909c9f0007d4e1b5). I am obviously doing something wrong, but not sure what.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem can be fixed by using an older version of the 'prettier' package. Specifically

```
"prettier": "<=2.3.0",
```

in the 'dependencies' section of your package.json file

Found a related query [here](https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/issues/16820#issuecomment-1012161244) and its [related PR](https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/pull/17239/files), which helped resolve this.